# Homology in associated graded modules and Rees algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homology-cohomology

Let $0\longrightarrow A\longrightarrow B\longrightarrow C\longrightarrow0$ be an exact sequence of finitely generated modules over the Noetherian local ring $(R,m)$, suppose $p\subset R$ is an ideal such that the length of $R/p$-modules $A/pA, B/pB, C/pC$ is finite. Consider the Rees algebra

$$\mathcal R:=\mathcal R_p(R)=\cdots \bigoplus Rt^{-1}\bigoplus R\bigoplus pt\bigoplus p^2t^2\bigoplus\cdots.$$

Set
$$\mathcal R_p(A)=\cdots \bigoplus At^{-1}\bigoplus A\bigoplus pAt\bigoplus p^2At^2\bigoplus\cdots,$$ and similarly for $B$ and $C$. Thus we got a sequence (not necessarily exact) $$0\longrightarrow \mathcal R(A)\longrightarrow\mathcal R(B)\longrightarrow\mathcal R(C)\longrightarrow0.$$ Let $H$ be the homology of this sequence in the middle. Show that

$$H/t^{-1}H=\ker(gr_pB\to gr_pC)/im(gr_pA\to gr_pB),$$

while the kernel of multiplication by $t^{-1}$ on $H$ is $\ker t^{-1}:H(1)\to H=\ker(gr_pA\to gr_pB)$,

where $gr_pA=A/pA\bigoplus pA/p^2A\bigoplus p^2A/p^3A\bigoplus\cdots$ is a $gr_pR$-module.

I am not so sure what does the homology $H/t^{-1}H$ mean, since as far as I know about homology algebra, I merely see such notation, can anybody help me explain what that is ?

Comment: I suppose the homology of a short sequence which is not exact in the middle is ker/im.

Comment: @user26857 So for $H/t^{-1}H$, it's just like, first compute homology in terms of each homogenuos component, then take the quotient ? i.e. $\bigoplus $(ker/im)$_i$/$t^{-1}\bigoplus $(ker/im)$_i$ ?

Comment: Probably yes. (A reference would be helpful.)

Comment: @user26857 This is an exercise 12.10 in Eisenbed's commutative algebra, and I did it the way followed the above interpretation, and I think that's what he means as it did work